# DirectoryNotFoundException when running dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

I'm running a docker image using the dockerfile below for a .net core web API application. The image is generated, however when I run the container using this command `sudo docker run -p 8081:80 turingo/jobportalbackend` I have got a critical error related to the resources folder which appears not found :

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /app/Resources/
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
>      at JobPortal_Backend.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, SeedDatabase seeder) in /app/Startup.cs:line 99

[image: errorpage]

````
# Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore any dependencies (via NUGET)
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build our release
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Generate/Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"] ```
````

---

here is the contents of the .dockerignore

`# .dockerignore

Dockerfile
[b|B]in
[O|o]bj `

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `Startup.cs` around line 99? My guess is it's a relative path issue. Also, do you have anything in your `.dockerignore` that might be preventing the `Resources` folder from being copied into the container?

Comment: the startup.cs contains the static file configuration : app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("~/Resources")
            }); startup.cs contains the conconfiguration of the static file :

Comment: What was the solution to this please if you remember @ghada :) ?